# How to set geopoint on current location on map in android?

Tags: android

****Please tell me how to set the Geo-point to current location on start of program? I want to set an overlay balloon to current location of user in emulator on starting of the program marked as "you are here". My Code is here-****

```
package com.jbb;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class jbb_latitudeActivity extends MapActivity 
{    
    LocationManager lm;
    MyLocationListener locationListener;
    MapView mapView;
    MapController mc;
    GeoPoint geoPoint;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        geoPoint = new GeoPoint( (int) (12.949997* 1E6), (int) (80.140213 * 1E6));
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        mc = mapView.getController();
        mc.animateTo(geoPoint);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapView.setTraffic(true);
        List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                overlays.clear();
        overlays.add(new MyLocationListener());
        //---use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations---
        lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,new MyLocationListener());
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString() , 1).show();
    }

        }
   @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }        

    private class MyLocationListener extends Overlay implements LocationListener 
    {
          public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {                              // 1
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
                if (!shadow) {                                                                              // 2
                    Point point = new Point();
                    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPoint, point);                                      // 3
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.marker_default);   // 4
                    int x = point.x - bmp.getWidth() / 2;                                                   // 5                   inty=point.ybmp.getHeight();                                                      // 6         canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,x,y,null);                                                     // 7
                }
            }
         public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
        {   
            //---when user lifts his finger---
            if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
                GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                    (int) event.getX(),
                    (int) event.getY());
            }                            
            return false;
        }
         public boolean onTap(GeoPoint point, MapView mapView) 
         {

           String msg = "Lat:: " + point.getLatitudeE6()/1E6 + " - " + 
                        "Lon:: " + point.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
          Toast.makeText(mapView.getContext(), msg,1).show();
          return true;
         }
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            if (loc != null) {                
                Toast.makeText(mapView.getContext(), 
                    "Location changed : Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + 
                    " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(), 
                    1).show();

                GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));
                mc.animateTo(p);
                mc.setZoom(15);                
                mapView.invalidate();    
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(mapView.getContext(), "hee", 1).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(mapView.getContext(), "hee", 1).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
            Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(mapView.getContext(), "hee", 1).show();
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: output is coming to that fixed co-ordinates which i am giving but i want original location of user,can you please tell me??????

Comment: are you doing this on emulator?

Comment: please tell me that like on google-map software it shows user current location how i can show that location on starting of my program?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,you should have added the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Then try,

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider); 
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, new TestLocationListener());
```

instead of,

```
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,new MyLocationListener());
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me ...I hope it will help u. If like mark it.

```
public class MyGoogleMapActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText        txted           = null;
Button          btnSimple       = null;
MapView         gMapView        = null;
MapController   mc              = null;
Drawable        defaultMarker   = null;
GeoPoint        p               = null;
double lattitude=18.5297 ;
double longitude=73.8491 ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   txted=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id1);
    String currentLocation="Lattitude :"+lattitude+"  Longitude :"+longitude;
    txted.setText(currentLocation);

    gMapView=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.myGMap);
    p= new GeoPoint((int)(lattitude * 1E6), (int)(longitude * 1E6));


    Canvas canvas=new Canvas();
    MyLocationOverlay locationOverlay=new MyLocationOverlay();

    List<Overlay> list=gMapView.getOverlays();
    list.add(locationOverlay);

    ZoomControls zoomControls=(ZoomControls) gMapView.getZoomControls();
    zoomControls.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    gMapView.addView(zoomControls);
    gMapView.displayZoomControls(true);
    mc=gMapView.getController();
    mc.setCenter(p);
    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(14);
    LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, this);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location!=null){
        double lat=location.getLatitude();
        double lng=location.getLongitude();
         String currentLocation="Lattitude :"+lat+"  Longitude :"+lng;
            txted.setText(currentLocation);
            mc.animateTo(p);

    }

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
protected class MyLocationOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay{

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
            long when) {
        Paint paint=new Paint();
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
        Point myScreenCords= new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, myScreenCords);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.marker);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, myScreenCords.x, myScreenCords.y, paint);
        canvas.drawText("I m here...", myScreenCords.x,myScreenCords.y, paint);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {
         super.onTouchEvent(e, mapView);
         if(e.getAction()==1){
             GeoPoint gp=gMapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int)e.getX(),(int)e.getY());
         }
         return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: it doesn'w work for me. it justs display me the initial geopoint not my location.